# create a lineplot from a few variables

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe with 3 variables, each one is representing different time point for the same outcome (e.g. weight):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Time_1": [-4.5, -0.8, -3.0, 0.2, -2.5], \
                   "Time_2": [-3, -0.2, -2.5, 0.3, 1], "TIme_3": [-2, 0, -1, 0.5, 1]})
```

I want to plot a trajectory for this variable identical to this graph:
[image]

Where I have a first point of (0,0) for the basline and three additional points on X axis with the correspondign values.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `df.shift().fillna(0).cumsum().plot(marker='D')` to get a plot of the 3 variables together. Shift and fillna are used so that the first line can be 0 for all the variables.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"Time_1": [-4.5, -0.8, -3.0, 0.2, -2.5], \
                   "Time_2": [-3, -0.2, -2.5, 0.3, 1], "Time_3": [-2, 0, -1, 0.5, 1]})

df.shift().fillna(0).cumsum().plot(marker='D')
```

[image]

Comment: Ths is not what I want.. I want something similar to the plot I attached, with one line describing the difference from 0 (e.g. time 1 value is -2.12, time 2 value is -0.88)

Comment: Maybe you need a cumsum? If i understood well what do you mean, check the updated answer